# Lua - If and and, what is faster?

Tags: performance, if-statement, lua, runtime

When I check two conditions with and in lua, which way is faster in running time?

```
if bool and somefuntion() then
    do stuff
end
```

or

```
if bool then
    if somefuntion() then
        do stuff
    end
end
```

?

Comment: There might be a theoretical anwwer but in practise I doubt that it is measurable. Do you have issues with any of the sytax?

Comment: No, but the function has a long execution-time. I'm just wondering if it is runned when bool is false..

Comment: ah, then maybe you should have asked that question. But the answer below is correct.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Run `luac -l -p` on both fragments and you'll see that they generate exactly the same bytecode. So write whatever is clearer for you.

The reason they are the same is that Lua uses short-circuit evaluation for *and* and *or*, as mentioned by OllieB.

Answer (score 5):

Lua is lazily evalulated, so it should make no difference.

The same effect would be true of short circuit logical and (**&&**) in c/c++

Comment: What if the somefunction() is very long?

Comment: @Fox: I think you don't understand the terms laziy evalulated or short circuit operation. If bool is false, lua will not evaluate somefunction() at all, in either incarnation.