# Chaining Logical Operations in Lua

Tags: if-statement, lua, logical-operators

Is this the most efficient way to do this in Lua? Thank you!

```
if X >= 0 and Y >= 0 then
    if X1 <= 960 and Y1 <= 720 then
        someCode()
    else end
else end
```

Comment: Typically, the only way to tell if one method is truly faster than another is to profile both and see which one wins in the common case.

Comment: I hope you do have something inside the `else end` block.

Comment: Related question: [Lua - If and and, what is faster?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18509877/lua-if-and-and-what-is-faster)

Answer (score 1):

It is a good idea to avoid nested `if` statements, I would try a single `if` check.
The best way to be sure is to profile the functions and see what works faster.

```
-- Be paranoid and use lots of parenthesis:
if ( ( (X >= 0) and (Y >= 0) ) and ( (X1 <= 960) and (Y1 <= 720) ) ) then
    someCode()
end
```

This is the same but easier to read. Good code is not only fast, but easy to read.

```
local condition1 = ((X >= 0) and (Y >= 0))
local condition2 = ((X1 <= 960) and (Y1 <= 720))

if (condition1 and condition2) then
    someCode()
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use operators to make it a tad bit shorter:

```
if ((X >= 0 && Y >= 0) && (X1 <= 960 && Y1 <= 920)) then
    someCode()
end
```

The answer by Yowza should also suffice tho, if you're looking for readability.